# Debian Cannot Access Internet Despite Being "Connected"

Tags: debian, wifi, internet, wicd

I'm have a problem, I cannot access the internet. I'm using a dell inspiron 6400 with debian kernel 3.2 installed. My windows manager is xfce4. I was never able to figure out the wired network, however at my home I had the wireless network working just fine. I'm at my mom's house now, and I can't get the wireless to connect. I connected with wicd, and it says that I'm connected, however I can't access the internet(seems very strange).

I have a CS assignment due before I get home, so I need to figure this out very quickly. Is there anything I can do to determine my connectivity?

Thanks for the help guys, just ask if you need any additional info.

Comment: Are your gateway and nameserver correct? Can you ping your router / access point or another host in your local network? Can you ping an Internet host (e.g. 173.194.69.139 or 193.99.144.80)?

Comment: The only way I can "connect" is by selecting WEP (Hex [0-9/A-F]). I can ping the router. However the dns seems messed up. The rest of the computers on the network are having no trouble at all.

Answer (score 7):

The wifi being "connected" only gives you the physical layer.

Are your IP settings plausable? Did you set static IP because DHCP didn't work at home?

```
ifconfig wlan0 (or name of wifi interface)
```

Check routing

```
route -n
```

Do you have a default gateway? If not, set the correct one

```
route add default gw <ip of gateway>
```

Can you ping an internal address (The router?)

```
ping <router address>
```

Can you ping externally?

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Is DNS set correctly?

```
nslookup google.com
```

No? Then set it manually for now:

```
nano -w /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```